# Using Network Links updates successfully with ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: kml, arcgis-explorer, kml-network-link

I've been trying to do updates of kml through a network link without success.

Here is an example from the KML 2.1 tutorial.

Load the following file (Point-load.kml) into AGX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Loads Point.kml</name>
  <Link>
    <href>http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/Point.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

This should create two placemarks.

Then load the following file (Update-load.kml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Update</name>
  <Link>
    <href>http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/NetworkLinkControl-Update.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

This should update one of the Placemarks to a different name and does in Google Earth, but doesn't seem to work in ArcGIS Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need ArcGIS Server for more capabilities...

ArcGIS Server Manager and KML

1. How do I create a KML network link using ArcGIS Server?

   **When authoring a Map Service using ArcGIS Server Manager, there is an option to enable KML capabilities for the service. Enabling this option exposes more configuration options for the service that are explicitly for KML.**

   A Map Service with the KML capability enabled allows any KML client, such as ArcGlobe, ArcGIS Explorer, Google Earth and Google Maps, to request data from the service in KML format.

   See Managing KML network links in the ArcGIS Server Help Online for details about creating and managing KML network links.

   Like all Map Services, a KML-enabled Map Service is created from a map document authored in ArcMap.

http://forums.arcgis.com/search.php?searchid=338867

Comment: The kml is generated by a custom application, I'm not sure how that would work with ArcGIS Server. Can the server pass through kml from a third party?

Comment: Does that mean that ArcGIS Desktop does not support the full KML standard? Do you know of an authoritative source on what it does and does not support?

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Data Interoperability [document](http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/data-interop-formats.pdf) details which data formats are supported by ArcGIS Desktop though its optional Interoperability Extension. There is also a [FAQ](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/common-questions.html) page and [whole section](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/index.html) devoted to it.